# Plotting a Time Schedule with Business Hour

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scheduling, xticks

I'm implementing a time schedule associated with business hour (8am to 5pm) using pd.offsets.CustomBusinessHour and attempting to plot the gantt chart or horizonal bar chart using matplotlib.
At this point, I want to cut off the interval between x-axis ticks out of business hour which is unnecessary. It seems like breaking hours exist between 5pm of d-day and 8am of d+1 day

[image: (As-Is) Chart Image]
[image: (To-Be) Chart Image]

I searched parameter configuration of BusinessHour method, way of tick setting using keyword 'interval', 'spacing', however I couldn't find appropriate solution.
I considered other plotting approaches using matplotlib.dates module but the result was in vain.

And this is my python code.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta, time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

num = 6

start_time = datetime(2021, 7, 7, 13, 5, 16, 268902)
int_to_time = pd.offsets.CustomBusinessHour(start="08:00", end="17:00", weekmask="1111111")

duration = num * int_to_time

horizon = [start_time + (i+1) * int_to_time for i in range(num+1)]
horizon = [i.replace(microsecond=0) for i in horizon]

fig, gnt = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,3))

gnt.barh(y=1, width=duration, left=start_time, color="cyan", height=0.2)

gnt.set_xticks(horizon)
gnt.set_xticklabels(horizon, rotation=90)

gnt.tick_params(bottom=False, labelbottom=False, top=True, labeltop=True)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to develop a Gantt chart and are having issues with spacing of the x axis labels. Your x-axis is representing Timestamps and you want them evenly spaced out (hourly).

Axis tick locations are determined by [Tick Locators](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-locators.html) and the labels are determined by [Tick Formatters](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-formatters.html). The default tick locator for datetimes is [AutoDatesLocator](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.AutoDateLocator) which is likely implementing [HourLocator](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.HourLocator). This will return x and y values that correspond to a 24 hour date time axis.

One solution to your problem is to simply use LinearLocator or FixedLocator along with a FixedFormatter. This puts you in very direct control over the tick locations and labels.

I must add that there are many tutorials and posts about how to make a Gantt chart with matplotlib or plotly that are easily searchable. I recommend reviewing some of those as you develop your plots.

The solution is implemented below in the context of your code.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta, time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

num = 6

start_time = datetime(2021, 7, 7, 13, 5, 16, 268902)
int_to_time = pd.offsets.CustomBusinessHour(start="08:00", end="17:00", weekmask="1111111")

duration = num * int_to_time

horizon = [start_time + (i+1) * int_to_time for i in range(num+1)]
horizon = [i.replace(microsecond=0) for i in horizon]

fig, gnt = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,3))

gnt.barh(y=1, width=duration, left=start_time, color="cyan", height=0.2)

gnt.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.LinearLocator(7))
gnt.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(horizon))

gnt.tick_params(bottom=False, labelbottom=False, top=True, labeltop=True, rotation=90)
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply, Coup.

I was aware of locator and formatter usage, but at this time I come to understand how to handle them specifically thanks to you.